# Manually Control Linear Workflow

Tags: materials, image, color-management

From what I've read about linear workflow, it might be causing this problem. If so, how can I manually control linear workflow in blender? Here's what's happening:

I am trying to make a shiny surface with lights in it for a game. This is a render when the lights are inactive:
[image: inactive lights are rendered as diffuse shaders.]

But when I change them to an emission shader, the image as a whole dims. 
[image: lights rendered with emission shader]

This is a problem because in my game, I want to be able to overlay the lights as active or inactive, but since the images are different brightnesses, it's very obvious that it was cut and pasted on.
[image: problem overlaid]

Comment: This problem is not related to linear workflow or color spaces. Linear workflow will not darken or lighten the image as a whole based on changes somewhere else in the image, it works per pixel.

It's not clear from your description what exactly you change between the first and second render. The arrows became green, the texture on the cylinder changed, and probably something else changed as well to make the floor darker.

Probably you need to use render layers or ray visibility to separate the changing objects and ensure they have no influence on the other objects.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly :) could you write that as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: Well, at least it's working in the lq previews. I will try rendering it better and tell you if it still works.

Comment: It still works on higher quality renders :D